# Retrieve SAML using ADAL library

Tags: adal, adal.js

Can adal.js library or adal-node.js library can be used to retrieve SAML2 token from Azure AD? If so, how?

I've tried using the example provided [here](https://github.com/dtjohnson/aws-azure-login). Although the solution works, I was not able to integrate it with express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is NO: ADAL.JS does not support SAML2 tokens