# Can I use the Azure Active Directory libraries (ADAL) to get a SAML response from Azure AD?

Tags: azure, saml, adal

I want to write a script that:

1. Logs a user into Azure AD with the [device code mechanism](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/wiki/Device-Code)
2. Constructs a [SAML SSO request URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-saml-protocol)
3. Makes the SAML request using the auth from step 1
4. Gets the SAML response back, and does something with it (not just open it in a browser)

Is there a way to do that with the Azure AD libraries?

I feel like this should be possible and I’m just missing something. Any ideas?
I've tried a bunch of stuff and experimented with code in the Python library, but to no avail.

I would prefer Python, but I can run it in a Docker image so language isn’t so important.

---

#### Context

At work, we use Azure AD for authentication, and we can log into the AWS Console using Azure AD and SSO SAML.

If I construct an appropriate SAML request URL and open it in my browser, I go through the in-browser auth flow. When I’m logged in, Azure AD returns a SAML response, and eventually my browser redirects me to the AWS console. It’s a URL of the form:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/11111111-1111-1111-11111111111/saml2?SAMLRequest=<base64 encoded string>
```

Now I want to do a similar flow for AWS credentials – make a SAML request to log in, read the SAML response, create credentials using [assume_role_with_saml](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html?highlight=saml#STS.Client.assume_role_with_saml), then write those to `~/.aws/credentials`. I think that means I have to access the SAML response directly – the browser just drops me at the end of the redirect chain.

Any ideas?

---

#### Other ideas

- I’m aware of the [aws-azure-login npm package](https://github.com/sportradar/aws-azure-login) which does this by spinning up a headless browser – but it’s unmaintained and I’ve found it to be a flaky.
- Right now I have a Python script that opens the SAML request in Chrome (where I log in), then uses the [browsercookie library](https://pypi.org/project/browsercookie/) to raid Chrome’s cookie jar and use those for its HTTP requests. That works, but it feels weird to be copying cookies this way. Also, it doesn’t work if I’m ssh'd into a remote server.
- I found an answer from [a year and a half ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48467635/1558022) that says “ADAL.JS does not support SAML2 tokens”. Wondering if that might have changed, or am I still stuck?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-aws-cli-assume-role , it does what you want but with Okta instead of Azure AD as the identity provider. You should be able to replace the relevant Okta pieces with AAD.

Comment: Any solution you got @alexwlchan? Can you please answer your question? I am looking for the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

No - ADAL is OpenID Connect and returns a JWT token.

Why do you need to use SAML? Could you not use OpenID Connect?

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD does not support SAML tokens for the [device code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code).

[MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Device-Code-Flow) library from the Azure AD team supports this flow for apps. Please give this a try or you can write code against the [protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code) itself